# I can't find the Syntax Error writing a formula with FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-2],'PivotTable of DBS'!C[-2]:C[-1],2,0),"NOT FOUND")"
```

when I'm running the macro it show me

> "compile error: syntax error"

I don't know what I'm missing .

Answer (score 1):

May be its first cell reference as C[-2] and double quotes for Not Found words

Try This

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'PivotTable of DBS'!C[-2]:C[-1],2,0),""Not 
Found"")"
```

Comment: Oh.. I didnt know. Thanks Pᴇʜ